# Issue programming a math equation in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, math

I am trying to solve the following equation in my program:

> 7.7^2 x 0.012^2/(0.2145 x 1.67^(16/3))

That should equal : 0.002582 (this is verified w/ google & scientific calculator)

This is the code that I am using

```
CGFloat eX1 = pow(7.7, 2) * pow(0.012, 2)/(0.2145 * pow(1.67, (16/3)));

NSLog(@"%f",eX1);
```

And even though, I believe my code should give me the same results, it's actually giving me:0.002679

What am I doing wrong? What can I do to obtain the correct answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `(16/3)` to `(16.0/3.0)`. Otherwise `16/3` results in `5`, not `5.33333349`.

And you have `7.2` instead of `7.7` at the start.

Comment: I followed your suggestion @rmaddy however my result was now `0.002258` Any ideas as to why this may be?

Comment: You have a typo - You have `7.2` instead of `7.7`.